# call actual class method from generic template type Object

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, linked-list, generic-programming

//main of programm i create a object of book and insert it into generic linked list but im unable to access all methods of book in linklist class

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 LinkedList<Book> list;
    list = new LinkedList<>();
   Book a=new Book();
   a.setAuthur("ahsan");
   a.setName("DSA");
   a.setNoOfPages(12);


   list.insertFirst(a);

}
```

//Linked List class

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class LinkedList<AnyType> {
public class Node<AnyType>
{
private AnyType data;
private Node<AnyType> next;
public Node(AnyType data, Node<AnyType> next)
{
this.data = data;
this.next = next;
}

/**
 * @return the data
 */
public AnyType getData() {
    return data;
}

/**
 * @param data the data to set
 */
public void setData(AnyType data) {
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 * @return the next
 */
public Node<AnyType> getNext() {
    return next;
}

/**
 * @param next the next to set
 */
public void setNext(Node<AnyType> next) {
    this.next = next;
}


}

 private Node<AnyType> head;

/*
*  Constructs an empty list
*/
public LinkedList()
{
head = null;
}




 public boolean isEmpty()
 {
   return head == null;
 }
 /*
 *  Inserts a new node at the beginning of this list.
 *  @param item to be inserted in First
 */
  public void insertFirst(AnyType item)
  {
  head = new Node<AnyType>(item, head);
  }
  /*
  *  Returns the first element in the list.
  *  @return First element in linked List
  */
  public AnyType getFirst()
  {
  if(head == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
  return head.getData();
  }
/*
 *  Removes the first element in the list.
 *  @return Deleted First Item
 */
  public AnyType deleteFirst()
  {
    AnyType tmp = getFirst();
    head = head.getNext();
    return tmp;
  }
 /*
  *  Recursively inserts a new node to the end of this list.
  *  @param item to be inserted in last
  */
  public void insertLast(AnyType item)
  { 
       if( head == null)
        insertFirst(item);
       else
        insertLast(head, item);
  }
  private void insertLast(Node<AnyType> node, AnyType item)
  {
    if(node.getNext() != null) insertLast(node.getNext(), item);
    else
    node.setNext( new Node<AnyType>(item, null));
  }
```

//want to get the actual name and auther name of book here in display list method

```
  /*
  *   Display all the elements in linked list
  */
  public void DisplayList()
  {
    Node<AnyType> Current=head;
    while(Current!=null)
    {
        System.out.print("[ "+ Current.getData()+" ] -> ");//want to     print name of the book here
       //i do the following but not worked Current.getData().getName();
        Current=Current.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println("NULL");
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you familiar with the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) idiom? The generic nature of your class says "I can handle anything" but the DisplayList method says "I can only handle books". Which one must prevale?

Comment: `AnyType` as its name suggest can represent any type, so it is not guaranteed that it will be Book. It can be type without `getData()` method. Simplest solution would be using method which all types have like `toString()`. Simply override this method in your `Book` class and return in it data which you want to print.

Comment: Thanks alot Pshemo but is there any way to call every method of book in linked list

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: When you have a `Node<AnyType>`, all we know is that the value is some instance of `AnyType`.  It might be a `Book`, or it might not.  As this is something we cannot know at compile time, we cannot allow methods to be called that are in `Book` but not `AnyType`.

If your requirement is to pull books out of your list, you should make it a `Node<Book>`.

Comment: Where is `toString()` coming into this?  It's not mentioned either in your question or my answer.

Comment: like there is no way of that i call the methode of class book from gen type node

Comment: You can do it if it is a `Node<Book>`.  You cannot if it is a `Node<AnyType>`.

Comment: no no i mean to say toString() function override give me some libarty to print the book data in linked list but i still can not be able to access the methods of book as you said its not possible while im using gen type node

Comment: The `toString()` method is available on every `Object` that exists in Java.  You can override it in `Book` to do whatever you want.  But on a more fundamental level... why does it have to be a `Node<AnyType>`?  What do you want it to do if it is actually, say, a `Node<Fish>`?  You need to think about these things.

Comment: actually i want to implement code generic for every type of object like the builtin linked list do the thing

Comment: In that case, `toString()` is the way to go.